# Accumulo Gora Mapping for Array/HashMap

Tags: avro, accumulo, gora

I'm able to integrate Apache Gora as ORM with Accumulo using the Avro JSON specification (which is bundled within Gora). It works fine when I use primitive data types such as String , Integer etc. but I run into errors once I define the data type as Array or Map.

In the case of Array , Gora throws the following error when I try to add a new element :

"org.apache.gora.persistency.ListGenericArray.add(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z"

With a Map , although I don't get an error , all I see an empty JSON object '{}' after commit ... the key/value pairs are missing.

This is what my JSON spec looks like

```
{
"type": "record",
"name": "Sample",
"namespace": "com.sample.goraz",
"fields": 
 [
    {"name": "first_name", "type": "string"},
    {"name":"last_name","type":"string"},
    {"name":"bucket","type":{"type":"map","values":"string"}},
    {"name":"stack","type":{"type":"array","items":"int"}}
 ]
}
```

This is the Accumulo-Gora xml mapping

```
<root>
<gora-orm>
    <class table="SampleCollection" keyClass="java.lang.String" name="com.sample.goraz.Sample">
        <field name="first_name" family="f" qualifier="q1" />
        <field name="last_name" family="f" qualifier="q2" />            
        <field name="bucket"  family="f" qualifier="q3" />
        <field name="stack"  family="f" qualifier="q4" />
    </class>
</gora-orm>
```

I'm using Accumulo Version 1.5 and Gora Version 0.3. I also tried with Accumulo Version 1.4.4 but face the same problem.

I'm not sure if Gora supports Map or Array data types ; I would imagine it should convert the complex data types into its equivalent JSON format and store that as a Char Sequence in Accumulo.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to note which fix the problem -

- Its invalid to mix different complex data types under the same column family. This means each complex type like Array or Map must belong to a different Column Family and defined accordingly in the ORM xml mapping.
- For complex data types , you only need to specify the Column Family and not the Column Qualifier ; thats because Gora would create the Qualifier. In Array the Column Qualifier is index and for a Map its the Key. In case you do specify a Column Qualifier , you'd end up with erratic data or just an empty set.
- The Gora Compiler creates a Java src file based on the JSON input template ... inside which field type 'array' is generated as a Java GenericArray ; on run-time Gora throws a 'AbstractMethodError' (possibly a bug in Gora). I resolved it by changing the Java field datatype to ListGenericArray.

Finally the ORM mapping file should look like this ::

```
<root>
<gora-orm>
    <class table="SampleCollection" keyClass="java.lang.String" name="com.sample.goraz.Sample">
        <field name="first_name" family="f" qualifier="q1" />
        <field name="last_name" family="f" qualifier="q2" />
        <field name="bucket"  family="g" />
        <field name="stack"  family="h"  />
    </class>
</gora-orm>
```

and you get a clean insert into Accumulo for Simple and Complex types.